# Verify md5 hash password with swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, swift2, xcode7

Im trying to get a `NSData` object from a Blob to load it into a Web View. I've read the documentation about SQLite.swift but I've nothing clear. Please, help me. I think I need a working example.

my code:
https://gist.github.com/gobozgz/9d1b02364f878bc1a026

```
import UIKit
import SQLite
class AreaInfoViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Here I Will load the webView PDFFile into the webView
        // webView.loadRequest(getAreaPdf())
        }

    func getAreaPdf () -> NSDATA {
        var myPdf:NSDATA // I think this is wrong

        let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        let docsDir = dirPaths[0]
        let databasePath = docsDir.stringByAppendingString("/db.sqlite")
        let db = try! Connection(databasePath, readonly: true)

        let areas = Table("areas")
        let id = Expression<Int64>("id")
        let name = Expression<String>("name")
        let pdffile = Expression<SQLite.Blob>("pdffile")
        let query = areas.select(id,name,pdffile)
            .filter(id == 1)
            .limit(1)
        let result = db.prepare(query)
        for row in result {
            myPdf = row[pdffile] // Obviusly this is wrong
        }
        return myPdf // Obviusly this is wrong too
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? BTW I hope you understand that md5 is a week hash function which is _not_ suitable for password hashing.

Comment: I think I made a mistake and edited a wrong question. Finally I used JKBCrypt and Bcript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used bcrypt instead md5. I used JKBCrypt and the JKBCrypt.verifyPassword

Since I was using password stored from a php generated hash I had to a little trick:

```
 var hash = user[password]
 let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\$2y\\$10\\$", options: .CaseInsensitive)
 hash = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(hash, options: [], range: NSRange(0..<hash.utf16.count), withTemplate: "\\$2a\\$10\\$")
 auth = JKBCrypt.verifyPassword(userPassword, matchesHash: hash)!
```